# Intuitive definition of pi without reference to space

Tags: geometry

Let's say you were trying to explain the significance of $\pi$ to an entity which lived in a computer and had no intuitive sense of what "space" is. So you can't just draw a circle and say "circumference over diameter".

Without space, is $\pi$ still meaningful?

A starting point I can think of is that $2 \pi$ is the "length" of the solution to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. But then you need to define length in a simple, symbolically motivated way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some people think we're entities that live in a computer. Can you say more about why you think that such entities would have no conception of space? In any event, there are dozens of [closed form expressions for pi](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html).

Comment: You can easily explain the *value* of $\pi$ by using a series expansion.  Explaining the concept of $\pi$ without geometry is much more challenging.

Comment: There are several infinite sums and other means of approximation that can be used for the value of pi.  See for instance those outlined [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_π).

Comment: Yes, as Michael points out, there are lots of infinite sums for lots of constants. The challenge is to say why $\pi$ is important.

Comment: Generate N points (x, y) uniformly where $-r\le{x}\le{r}$ and $-r\le{y}\le{r}$. Count the M points for which $x^2+y^2\le{r^2}$. For large N the ratio M/4N approximates $\pi$ independently of r. Should be meaningful in computer world!

Comment: Oops - should be M/N approximates $\pi$/4

Answer (score 2):

Here an analytic definition (resting on a couple of theorems, albeit theorems one could prove in about two 50-minute class meetings toward the end of a good calculus course).

There exists a unique twice-differentiable function $C$ satisfying
$$
C'' + C = 0,\qquad C(0) = 1,\quad C'(0) = 0.
$$
It turns out this function is periodic and non-constant: There exists a smallest positive real number (denoted $2\pi$) such that
$$
C(x + 2\pi) = C(x)\quad\text{for all real $x$.}
$$

Or, with a bit less work: There exists a smallest positive real root of $C$ (denoted $\pi/2$).

Comment: Ooo, this is a deep answer. Periodicity is the kind of thing I should have been thinking about. Lemme think on this.